# VB.net warning with VB6 code: how to fix it?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, warnings, compatibility, obsolete

How can I use this code:

```
VB6.LoadResString(i)
```

without getting this warning:

```
Public Function LoadResString(ID As Integer) As String is obsolete: 
'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.* classes are obsolete and supported 
within 32 bit processes only. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=160862'.
```

The posted link in the error and other info in the MSDN site only say to me "ehy, this is obsolete in your framework, don't use it", but what if I need it (Loads a string from a resource (.res) file.)?

How can I write it without getting that warning message?

UPDATE: Thanks, but nothing worked...

Comment: It doesn't actually load a string from a .res file so pretty unlikely that your assumption that you need it is accurate.  Use Project + Properties, Resources instead.

Comment: In VB6 `LoadResString` [does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa244131(v=vs.60).aspx) load a string from the project resources. The best way to do this in VB.Net is to use the .Net resources as Hans says. If you are copying/migrating VB6 code you will also need to get the strings from the VB6 resources e.g. using the VB6 IDE